# Perl Regex to exclude certain strings within the middle of a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string:

```
The file FILENAME has not been received
```

I'm trying to get the regex to match this, but not if the string is this (for example):

```
The file FAILNAME has not been received
```

I've got this regex so far:

```
/^(?=.*?\bThe\sfile\b)((?!FAILNAME).)*$/
```

But I'm unsure how to continue the expected text after the exclusion.

I hope I've explained that correctly :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What parts of the string are varying? What's wrong with `/^The file FILENAME has not been received$/`?

Comment: Thank you, the FILENAME is variable.  Should a specific filename appear in the string I want the match to fail.  But if any other filename appears, I need a match.  Hope that clarifies.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it in two steps:

```
if ($message =~ /\AThe file (\S+) has not been received\z/ && $1 ne 'FAILNAME') {
```

I.e. use a regex to validate the general format and extract the filename, then check the extracted name separately.

Why cram everything into a single regex?

Speaking of which, you can actually cram arbitrary conditions into a regex. I wouldn't recommend it in this case, but:

```
/\AThe file (\S+) has not been received\z(?(?{ $1 eq 'FAILNAME' })(*FAIL))/
```

This extended pattern essentially says "if `$1` equals `FAILNAME`, fail the match".

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a pattern error on a demo: https://regex101.com/r/j4VSVw/1

Comment: @greenage That's because my answer assumes Perl, but regex101 uses PHP (and the PCRE library).

Answer (score 1):

You could move the negative lookahead to after `file` followed by a whitespace character to assert what is directly on the right is not `FAILNAME`:

```
^The\sfile\s(?!\bFAILNAME\b).*$
```

Or of it can not occur in the string after `The file` use a quantifier:

```
^The\sfile\s(?!.*\bFAILNAME\b).*$
```

If there can not be anything before and after `FAILNAME` you could lookarounds:

```
^The\sfile\s(?!.*(?<!\S)FAILNAME(?!\S)).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/88oL1D/1)

Comment: That would also reject `FAILNAME-NOT`. Your second regex even rejects `NOT-FAILNAME`.

Comment: @ melpomene You are right, thank you! I have added a word boundaries.

Comment: Anda a version with lookarounds as well.

Comment: That last one will fail reject `NOT A FAILNAME`.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that we wish to fail those that have `FAILNAME`, which your original expression seems to be working fine, and we'd then slightly modify that, which this might work:

```
^(?=The\sfile\s)(?!.*\s\bFAILNAME\b\s.*).*$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/ApibxX/1/)

Here we are adding two spaces as an extra left and right boundaries, which if we do not wish to have those, we'd be simply excluding.

#### Example

```
use strict;

my $str = 'The file FILENAME has not been received
The file FILENAME has been received
The file FILENAME
The file AFAILNAME has not been received
FILENAME
The file FAILNAME has not been received
FAILNAME has not been received
The file FAILNAME


';
my $regex = qr/^(?=The\sfile\s)(?!.*\s\bFAILNAME\b\s.*).*$/mp;

if ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
  print "Whole match is ${^MATCH} and its start/end positions can be obtained via \$-[0] and \$+[0]\n";
  # print "Capture Group 1 is $1 and its start/end positions can be obtained via \$-[1] and \$+[1]\n";
  # print "Capture Group 2 is $2 ... and so on\n";
}

# ${^POSTMATCH} and ${^PREMATCH} are also available with the use of '/p'
# Named capture groups can be called via $+{name}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Why a separate `$regex` variable? Why `/g`? What "named capture groups"?

Comment: Thanks all, the filename is a variable, so if the file name in the middle of the entire string is FAILNAME then it should fail to match.  But anything else, should match.  As you mention, my regex works if my string ends at the filename.  But there is extra text which I'd like to also match.  Just exclude the FAILNAME.  Trying to avoid matching a particular filename should it appear in the string.